# Ionic - Cannot read property 'findall' of null

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am getting this error whenever I run ionic cordova run android.  I would post more stuff but I have literally no idea where to start to solve this problem and there doesn't seem to be many google posts on this.  This was working about an hour ago and I've changed a variable name in that time.  Has anyone ever run into this before?

[image]

Comment: Check here, probably similar problem: [LINK](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2623)

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up fixing this by creating a new project with ionic start and copying the project over.  It fixed it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem and I tried this and now its working :

```
ionic cordova platform rm android

ionic cordova platform add android
```